# Any obvious reason why the font color is not ending up what I set it as in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, fonts, colors

I'm setting a font in a tab as 0x999999, but it's coming out a green/grey.

Here's my theme code:

```
import flash.text.Font;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;

public class Theme 
{
    [Embed(source = "fonts/Volter__28Goldfish_29.ttf", fontName="Volter (Goldfish)",mimeType="application/x-font", unicodeRange='U+0020-U+007E')]
    static private var EmbededVolter:Class;
    static private var inited:Boolean;
    static public function init():void {
        if (inited) return;
        try{
            Font.registerFont(getDefinitionByName("Volter") as Class);
        }catch(e:Error){
            Font.registerFont(EmbededVolter);
        }
        inited = true;
    }
    static public var fontVolterSize:uint = 9;
    static public var textColor:uint = 0x999999
    static public var embedFonts:Boolean = false;
    static public var defaultTextFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat("Volter (Goldfish)", fontVolterSize, textColor);        
}
```

The code for setting the tab properties:

```
public function TabTitle(name:String) {
    this.name = name;
    this.mouseChildren = false;
    this.buttonMode = true;     
    bg = new Shape();
    bg.alpha = 0;
    bg.graphics.beginFill(0x2A2A2A);
    bg.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 30);
    bg.graphics.endFill();
    addChild(bg);
    t = new TextField();
    t.x = 10;
    t.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
    t.defaultTextFormat = Theme.defaultTextFormat;
    t.text = name;
    t.y = 7;
    bg.width = t.width + 20;
    addChild(t);
    addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, handleOver);
    addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, handleOver);         
}
```

And the difference in color between the above dynamic set font (top text) and the same font set to 0x999999 in a static text field (bottom):

[image]

I don't have any transparent alpha setting on the font, but if I did, the background is a grey shade anyway.

Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're embedding the font, you need to tell it to your TextField :

```
t.embedFonts = true;
```

Comment: Thanks blue112, but setting t.embedFonts = true; makes the text disappear.

Comment: If it disappears, it means it wasn't correctly embed.